# Button disabilitation based on class + data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I'm writing an `<input type="number">` with `-` and `+` button for an ecommerce cart.

The structure of each group is:

- 1x `<button class="minus" data-prod="prod_id_int">`
- 1x `<input type="number" id="prod_id_int">`
- 1x `<button class="plus" data-prod="prod_id_int">`

What I'm trying to do now is disabling the button `-` if the value of the input type number is `< 1`.

To achieve it, based on my script, I have to disable not the general `<button class="minus">` but the specific `<button class="minus" data-prod="prod_id_int">`.
I tried this

```
$(buttonClass).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', true);
```

and it actually prevents the quantity from being `< 1` BUT it doesn't really add the property `disabled` to the button. I'm not sure, then, that it's the right way. Can someone explain me how to achieve it?

**Here the working snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var buttonClass = $(this).attr('class');
    //console.log(buttonClass);
    var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
    //console.log(buttonID);
    var dataProd = $(this).data('prod');
    var inputToChange = $('#' + dataProd);
    var inputToChangeValue = $('#' + dataProd).val();
    if (buttonClass == 'minus') {
      var newValue = parseInt(inputToChangeValue) - parseInt(1);
      if (newValue < 1) {
        $(buttonClass).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', true);
        //$(buttonClass).data('prod="' + dataProd + '"').prop('disabled', true);
        //$(buttonClass + '.[data-prod="' + dataProd + '"]').attr(disabled=disabled); //.prop('disabled', true)
        //alert('NOPE');
      } else {
        $('#' + dataProd).val(newValue);
        //console.log(inputToChangeValue);
      }
    } else if (buttonClass == 'plus') {
      var newValue = parseInt(inputToChangeValue) + parseInt(1);
      if (newValue > 99) {
        alert('NOPPPPEE');
      } else {
        $('#' + dataProd).val(newValue);
        console.log(inputToChangeValue);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.plus,
.minus {
  width: 1.5%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #EF1B1F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="minus" data-prod="23">-</button>
<input type="number" class="qta" id="23" value="5">
<button class="plus" data-prod="23">+</button>
<br>
<button class="minus" data-prod="90">-</button>
<input type="number" class="qta" id="90" value="62">
<button class="plus" data-prod="90">+</button>
```

Comment: `$(buttonClass).prop('disabled', newValue < 1);` and what on earth is this?`parseInt(inputToChangeValue) - parseInt(1);` try `inputToChangeValue--`

Comment: The button does get disabled right?, because `prop('disabled', true)` is the way to do it

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the `--` tip, although it works if put it in front of the var as underlined by Alexandru-Ionut Mihai, not at the end. And I actually can't get this `$(buttonClass).prop('disabled', newValue < 1);`

Comment: $("."+buttonClass).prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution.

```
$('.'+buttonClass).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', true);
```

All you need is to `concatenate` `.` symbol to your class.

`buttonClass` returns only the `className`, such as `minus` and you need jquery `selector`, like this: `$('.minus')`

Also, I recommend you to use this: `var newValue = --inputToChangeValue;` for a simply way to decrement value, instead `var newValue = parseInt(inputToChangeValue) - parseInt(1);`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var buttonClass = $(this).attr('class');
    //console.log(buttonClass);
    var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
    //console.log(buttonID);
    var dataProd = $(this).data('prod');
    var inputToChange = $('#' + dataProd);
    var inputToChangeValue = $('#' + dataProd).val();
    if (buttonClass == 'minus') {
      var newValue = --inputToChangeValue;
      if (newValue < 1) {
        $('.'+buttonClass).filter(function() { 
            return $(this).data("prod") == dataProd 
          }).prop('disabled', true);
        //$(buttonClass).data('prod="' + dataProd + '"').prop('disabled', true);
        //$(buttonClass + '.[data-prod="' + dataProd + '"]').attr(disabled=disabled); //.prop('disabled', true)
        //alert('NOPE');
      } else {
        $('#' + dataProd).val(newValue);
        //console.log(inputToChangeValue);
      }
    } else if (buttonClass == 'plus') {
      var newValue = parseInt(inputToChangeValue) + parseInt(1);
      $('.minus').filter(function() { 
            return $(this).data("prod") == dataProd 
          }).prop('disabled', false);
      if (newValue > 99) {
        alert('NOPPPPEE');
      } else {
        $('#' + dataProd).val(newValue);
        console.log(inputToChangeValue);
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.plus,
.minus {
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #EF1B1F;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="minus" data-prod="23">-</button>
<input type="number" class="qta" id="23" value="5">
<button class="plus" data-prod="23">+</button>
<br>
<button class="minus" data-prod="90">-</button>
<input type="number" class="qta" id="90" value="12">
<button class="plus" data-prod="90">+</button>
```

Comment: +1 for having spotted the error (I completely forgot about the `.`) and for the suggestion `--inputToChangeValue`, but the script doesn't work either. Now it disables *all* the `<button class="minus">`, not just the one with `data-prod="23"` (for example); I guess then that this way `$('.' + buttonClass).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', true);` is not the correct one to achieve what I want. Any clue?

Comment: Yes, use this :`$(this).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', true);` .View updated answer.

Comment: This definitely works! Thanks Alexandru. Can you tell me why `$(this).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', true);` works but `$(.minus).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', true);` not? 'Cause I was now trying to re-enable the button in case the value is `> 1` using exactly `$(.minus).data('prod', dataProd).prop('disabled', false);` but the result is a mess

Comment: @brigo, `this` refers the button clicked.

Comment: @brigo, I updated my answer with a new solution for your problem, using `filter` function.